# Externalize Configuration angular build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jboss

I'm using jboss to deploy my angular project and have configuration file `enviroment.prod.ts` set as below.

```
import { KeycloakConfig } from 'keycloak-angular';
export const environment = {
  production: true,

  orgin: window['orgin'],
  baseURL: window['baseURL'],
  ClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  ClientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  AuthorizeUrl: window['AuthorizeUrl'],
  TokenGenerationUrl: window['TokenGenerationUrl'],
  RedirectURL: window['RedirectURL'],
  GetLoggedInUserInfo: window['GetLoggedInUserInfo'],
  fileUploadURL: window['fileUploadURL'],
  keycloak: keycloakConfig,
```

and in jboss domain.xml configuration file i have set system properties which i want to read in angular project so i can have on single war file to deploy in multiple env (ie sit, uat, prod).

```
  <system-properties>
        <property name="orgin" value="xxxxxx"/>
        <property name="baseURL" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="AuthorizeUrl" value="xxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="TokenGenerationUrl" value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="RedirectURL" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="GetLoggedInUserInfo" value="xxxxxxx"/>
        <property name="fileUploadURL" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
    </system-properties>
```

but am not able to achieve what I wants i have tried to do `console.log(window['orgin']` but am getting undefined.

How to read this system property from jboss to my angular project? I am trying to learn angular.